# Typescript Enum dynamically accessing error

Tags: typescript, enums

I want access Enum like Routes[] but for some reason typescript is returning error

> Property 'Help' does not exist on type 'String'.

```
enum Routes {
    Help = 'help',
}

type test = Routes['Help'];
type test2 = Routes.Help;
```

Basicly I want to extend route name with some prefix like following

```
type TransformRoute<Type extends Record<string, string>, Prefix extends keyof typeof Routes> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as `${string & Prefix}${string & Property}`]: `${string & Routes[Prefix]}${string &
        Type[Property]}`;
};
```

But here i get error

> Type 'Prefix' cannot be used to index type 'Routes'.

Anyone has any input on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums are basically objects, so you must treat them like so when creating types from it. You can do this:

```
// Notice the keyof typeof in ${string & keyof typeof Routes[Prefix]}
type TransformRoute<Type extends Record<string, string>, Prefix extends keyof typeof Routes> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as `${string & Prefix}${string & Property}`]: `${string & keyof typeof Routes[Prefix]}${string &
        Type[Property]}`;
};
```

You can play with it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASg9mALsAzlA3gKCjqAJYAGwAcoBeKAcgAsjjKAabXAFVUXKgCJkVEBLEAHMumAL6ZEAT2LAobPvCTAAPAAUATsABm-AB5Rge5CAAmaANbApcbVGmzbsBLwB8nAAYASdHw2ChKAAyexlgJyVeAG1NHX0AXTEPTEwAelTQ2Sh+NDgQQiluWhJRAGM8vnt2AC55dkjVLgIS9wouYuIuAG4U9My5HKg8gu5eAWEyio4xgCZahUQGlS4FrlbR9gDuoA).